# Batch Create Circle Sections based on center point, radius and azimuth range

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geoprocessing

I have over 1000 points with radius and min/max azimuth. I need to create a circle section based on these three columns for each point (buffer each point by radius but only keep the section between min and max azimuth). Anyone has a good way to do this?

Comment: How 355-10 ,i.e. narrow north facing sector represented in your data?

Comment: The azimuth range is 60 degree for all the cases.

Comment: How 330 - 30 sector is stored?

Comment: I see your point and thank you for pointing it out. I didn't thought of that. I guess I also need to tell the program which azimuth goes first.

Comment: The original problem I am trying to solve here is that I have over 1000 points with same radius. Each point has a line attached to it. I need to slice the buffer circle at +30/-30 azimuth from the line. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your points table has this structure:
[image]

Buffer them (shapefile) by known radius (R) and run this field calculator expression on field "Shape":

```
from math import radians,sin,cos
def sector (A,X,Y,R):
 arr=arcpy.Array(arcpy.Point(X,Y))
 for i in range (-30,31):
  a=radians(A+i )
  arr.add(arcpy.Point(X+R*sin(a),Y+R*cos(a)))
  pgon=arcpy.Polygon(arr)
 return pgon
'-------------------
sector ( !BEARING!, !POINT_X!, !POINT_Y!,50)
```

In the picture below original points labelled by values stored in BEARING field:

[image]

Comment: Excellent. Thank you so much.

Comment: Tick as solved please.